# How to detect unclosed brackets in XML parsing

Tags: php, xml, regex, parsing

In case the provider supplies a XML string that does not parse due to parse errors (and thet will not fix this for a while), I was wondering if it is possible to perform some validations to detect and correct the XML so it will be fail-proof.

Some examples of issues can be:

The rule of thumb is to get `<>` replaced for `&lt;&gt;`

- Lonely `<` replaced for `&lt;`
- Words like `<this>` that are not XML tags (the criteria can be to replace the `<` and `>` symbols to ignore the unclosed tag.
- Math formulas like this: `5<x<10`

I can't come with more scenarios at the moment, and I think I detected one o those with regex, but that is not enought.

I would like to read your comments.

Comment: This isn't a chatroom. You have used a regex, can you show it? Why isn't it enough ? And why is the XML broken in the first place ? Could you show some sample input and expected output ?

Comment: @HamZa I've used regex to solve the words like <this> but it cannot be used for all the cases. I know that this is not a chat room, but I already read some interesting answers and criteria, that was my intentions and sorry for let the disscussion open and not the way you liked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was wondering if it is possible to perform some validations to
>   detect and correct the XML so it will be fail-proof.

Your noble intentions are unfortunately misguided.  In a fundamental sense, communication mistakes cannot be repaired without relying upon some portion of the protocol being mistake-free.

You can only be so liberal in what you accept.  **Even [Postel's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robustness_principle) has its limits.**

Standard practice in building XML-based systems is to require that messages be well-formed XML.  (In fact, non-well-formed XML is not XML; see [Michael Kay's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20281878/290085).)  Especially when you cannot trust your sender to follow protocol, you should check your input.  One of the benefits of XML is that there exist battle-tested parsers to use to perform these checks.

Pull the message off the wire and immediately parse it using a known-reliable parser such as Xerces2.  If there are errors, pass them back to the sender to repair and do not attempt to process the message further.  If you have a schema, the parse should be conducted with validation turned on against the schema to detect higher-level errors in the protocol as well.

**Do not be tempted by the possibility of correcting "obvious" errors in an ad hoc manner.**  The problem is theoretically unsolvable in the general case, and attempts at applying piecemeal corrections will actually make your system less robust, not more.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using XML for data interchange. It's a great format. When people use XML, you have a wide choice of off-the-shelf parsers available which guarantee that everyone can read your data. By contrast, if you use home-brew formats that are not standardised and not documented then deciphering the data becomes a nightmare.

I would also recommend that if you are using a home-brew format for data interchange, you don't call it XML, because you will only confuse people.

If you want help here in how to parse a home-brew non-XML data interchange format, please don't tag the question as "XML", because you reach the wrong audience. And please provide a specification of the format. I know you don't have one, but writing a program to read data in an unspecified format is not something any competent programmer should ever attempt.

Comment: If it has <> in it then it's not XML.